# useState depending on other state

Tags: react-hooks

I have this `useSiren` hook that should update its state with the incoming `json` argument but it doesnt.

On the first call the `json` is an empty object, because the fetch effect has not been run yet.
On the second call its also an empty object (triggered by `loading` getting set to true in `App`)
And on the third call its filled with valid data. However, the valid data is not applied. The state keeps its initial value.

I guess somehow `setSiren` must be called to update it, since initial state can only be set once. But how would I do that? Who should call `setSiren?

```
import { h, render } from 'https://unpkg.com/preact@latest?module';
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'https://unpkg.com/preact@latest/hooks/dist/hooks.module.js?module';
import htm from "https://unpkg.com/htm@latest/dist/htm.module.js?module";

const html = htm.bind(h);

function useFetch({
  method = "GET",
  autoFetch = true,
  href,
  body
}) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState()
  const [response, setResponse] = useState()
  const [isCancelled, cancel] = useState()
  const [json, setJson] = useState({})

  const sendRequest = async payload => {
    try {
      setLoading(true)
      setError(undefined)
      const response = await fetch(href.replace("http://", "https://"), {
        method
      })
      const json = await response.json()
      if (!isCancelled) {
        setJson(json)
        setResponse(response)
      }
      return json
    } catch (err) {
      if (!isCancelled) {
        setError(err)
      }
      throw err
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }

  if (autoFetch) {
    useEffect(() => {
      sendRequest(body)
      return () => cancel(true)
    }, [])
  }

  return [{
    loading,
    response,
    error,
    json
  }, 
    sendRequest
  ]
}

function useSiren(json) {
  const [{ entities = [], actions = [], links, title }, setSiren] = useState(json)
  const state = (entities.find(entity => entity.class === "state")) || {}
  return [
    {
      title,
      state,
      actions
    },
    setSiren
  ]
}

function Action(props) {
  const [{ loading, error, json }, sendRequest] = useFetch({ autoFetch: false, href: props.href, method: props.method })
  const requestAndUpdate = () => {
    sendRequest().then(props.onRefresh)
  }
  return (
    html`
      <button disabled=${loading} onClick=${requestAndUpdate}>
        ${props.title}
      </button>
    `
  )
}

function App() {
  const [{ loading, json }, sendRequest] = useFetch({ href: "https://restlr.io/toggle/0" })
  const [{ state, actions }, setSiren] = useSiren(json)
  return (
    html`<div>
      <div>State: ${loading ? "Loading..." : (state.properties && state.properties.value)}</div>
      ${actions.map(action => html`<${Action} href=${action.href} title=${action.title || action.name} method=${action.method} onRefresh=${setSiren}/>`)}
      <button disabled=${loading} onClick=${sendRequest}>
        REFRESH
      </button>
    </div>
    `
  );
}
render(html`<${App}/>`, document.body)
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe what you want to do is to update the `siren` state when the `json` param changes? You can use a useEffect to automatically update it.

```
function useSiren(json) {
  const [{ entities = [], actions = [], links, title }, setSiren] = useState(json)

  useEffect(() => { // here
    setSiren(json)
  }, [json])

  const state = (entities.find(entity => entity.class === "state")) || {}
  return [
    {
      title,
      state,
      actions
    },
    setSiren
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't thought of that. I tried to search for such use case online but did not find anything. Is that the recommended way to do such pattern?

Comment: @philk I think this is the most suitable way for this problem... personally.

Answer (score -1):

The pattern mentioned by @awmleer is packaged in [`use-selector`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-selector):

```js
import { useSelectorValue } from 'use-selector';

const { entities=[], actions=[], title} = json;

const siren = useSelectorValue(() => ({
  state: entities.find(entity => entity.class === 'state') || {},
  actions,
  title
}), [json]);
```

***Disclosure*** I'm author and maintainer of `use-selector`